# mysql fetch array returns false in function but not in the document

Tags: php, mysql, function, loops

i am creating a CMS and have php creating a page. i have a while loop like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
echo "some html code" . $row['name'];
```

its shortend but hopefully you get the point. i have the full thing in my page working just as it should and i wanted to move it to a function include as i want to reuse it. the problem is i do that and it stops working.

i did some testing and found that the function is getting the query result and after doing a var dump both were identical the problem comes when i try to assign it to an array. it comes back as false so in the above code, for example,

```
$row = false;
```

im toatly lost in this and if my explanation is confusing i appologise but i am a bit of a newbie i have tried searching but....i dont really know where to begin
any thoughts.

Comment: First of all don't use mysql_* functions it's deprecated use mysqli_*  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and see what errors you get

Comment: i had seen that but thanx as for errors i get none the problem isnt with the mysql query to the database its fine its just when i try to use it as a function.

Comment: please post your full code function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fugured it out
when i was testing the function i commented out the original code on the main page but for some reason i had not comented out enough (it was a mix of php and html clearly the php had not been commented out properly) this must have been causing a clash of some kind as when i put the function above the code on my page the function worked and the long code below it did not

sorry for wasting your time guys

Answer (score 0):

the query you are doing is basically wrong, try posting exactly the code which you have in `$query` and then let us see the problem.
also, it is better to use `mysqli` functions.
but for this, edit the question and type the query, or simply put a `die(mysql_error())` at the end of your query which is in `$query`. It will show your exact error.